# stl + memory management question

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, stl

For example, i have next code:

```
#include <set>
using namespace std;

struct SomeStruct 
{
    int a;
};

int main ()
{
    set<SomeStruct *> *some_cont = new set<SomeStruct *>;
    set<SomeStruct *>::iterator it;
    SomeStruct *tmp;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000; i ++)
    {
        tmp = new SomeStruct;
        tmp->a = i;
        some_cont->insert(tmp);
    }

    for (it = some_cont->begin(); it != some_cont->end(); it ++)
    {
        delete (*it);
    }

    some_cont->clear(); // <<<<THIS LINE
    delete some_cont;
    return 0;
}
```

Does "THIS LINE" need to be called before deleting some_cont for avoiding memory leaks or destructor will be called automatically?

Comment: By the way, your `typedef` should not have `()`

Comment: You should be aware that what you have here is some old school C style code, and not at all the right way to write that in C++.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to call it, destructor will be called for sure.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no need to clear the set before destroying it.

Note that there is very rarely a need to allocate an `std::set` (or any standard container) manually. You'd be much better off just putting it in automatic storage and letting C++ handle the cleanup for you:

So instead of

```
set<SomeStruct *> *some_cont = new set<SomeStruct *>;
```

use

```
set<SomeStruct *> some_cont;
```

then change all `some_cont->` to `some_cont.` and remove the `delete some_cont` (the container will be destroyed when `main` exits automatically.

The advantage to do things this way are:

1. You don't need to remember to delete the container, and
2. You don't need to do an expensive memory allocation up front.

It's also far more idomatic C++ to put things in automatic storage.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to explicitly clear a `set` before destroying the `set`.

OTOH, you do have a number of other problems ranging from lousy (Java-like) design, to incorrect syntax, to a missing operator to lots of potential memory leaks. While some of the design might make sense in Java or C#, it's a *really* poor idea in C++. Once we get rid of the most egregious problems, what we have left is something like this:

```
#include <set>

struct SomeStruct 
{
    int a;
    SomeStruct(int i) : a(i) {}
    bool operator<(SomeStruct const &other) const { return a < other.a; }
};

int main ()
{
    std::set<SomeStruct> some_cont;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000; i ++)
    {
        SomeStruct tmp(i);
        some_cont.insert(tmp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would even avoid using `tmp` (:

Comment: @Kiril: I probably would too -- but I was trying to retain as much of the original as possible while still being at least halfway reasonable. The other changes are (IMO) essential; that one would be desirable but optional.

Comment: Yes, but lifetime of my objects are starting and ending in different functions, so i need to use allocation and deallocation.

Comment: And i do not use "comparing" functions of set. I mean i don't care in what order they will be stored. Only i need are operations: put and get. Do i still need to declare "<" operator?

Comment: @Oleg: not really. When you insert something into a set, it gets copied into the set, and the set then owns the (copy of) the object. It will then have the lifetime of the set unless you delete it from the set first. Objects stored in a `set` need to be comparable. If you don't care about ordering (or at least uniqueness, which still depends on comparisons), you may want some other container.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: Thank you for reply. About object lifetime i meant that my set is creating in func1() than after several period(network response) func2(some_cont) is called, where it should be deleted. So if i will not create an object of set dynamically it will be freed in func1() and couldn't be read in func2().

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: About ordering, you're right. I should use vector instead. My fault.

Comment: It sounds a bit like `func1` and `func2` might make sense as members of the same class, with the `set` (or `vector`) as a member of the same class so the container and its contents exist for the life of the parent object.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: I think it is possible to make in the way you are saying, but i don't know how yet in my case. The problem is that i have Class1->Func1() and Class2->Func2(), Class1(2) doesn't know anything about Class2(1), because noone can be a father of other. They can talk only via "messaging".

Comment: @Oleg: If they're talking via messaging, presumably one of the objects exists at all times that the other does, so the collection may make the most sense as a member of that class. You haven't said enough about the rest of the design to make that certain, but as a first guess it seems halfway reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not, this will be done automatically in the set's destructor.

Answer (score 0):

The STL containers automatically free any memory they own. So in your case the place allocated to store your SomeStruct* will be freed by the destructor of set. Note that the destructor of set does not call any destructors of SomeStruct, so it's good you iterate over them to delete them yourself.

Comment: You're wrong - calling destructor of set _will call_ the destructors of _all_ `SomeStruct`, if they are allocated on the stack. The need to explicitly delete all allocated `SomeStruct` objects has nothing to do with `set`'s destructor.

Comment: @Kiril: But they aren't allocated on the stack. They are allocated using `new` in that 1000 iteration for loop. In that example, all those `SomeStruct`s will not be freed.

Comment: @Peter - yes, you're right and I don't say something else. I'm saying, that @danta is wrong about "Note that the destructor of set does not call any destructors of SomeStruct" - free-ing memory, allocated on the heap, has nothing to do with `set`'s destructor in this case, right?

Comment: if I remember good, boost has some containers that take ownership. So if you insert a SomeStruct pointer, it will take care of deleting it. I just wanted to mention that the stl containers do no such thing.

Comment: It's possible, I don't know. Sounds like some kind of container, using `auto_ptr` smart pointers. But still, `set` is not `boost` container and it calls the destructors of all objects (note - **objects**, not pointers), inserted into it.

Comment: clear manual:Erases all elements in a %set. Note that this function only erases the elements, and that if the elements themselves are pointers, the pointed-to memory is not touched in any way. Managing the pointer is the user's responsibilty.